# How to support multi language including RtL in android apps with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, local, rtl-language

```
private fun setLocale(lang: String) {
        val language = Locale(lang)
        val res: Resources = resources
        val dm: DisplayMetrics = res.displayMetrics
        val conf: Configuration = res.configuration
        conf.locale = language
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)
        val refresh = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(refresh)
        finish()
    }
```

Hello Everybody!

I'm creating an android app and this is for **Arabic people**. And I have created the string resources **for "en" and "ar" xml** and declared it in Mainfest.xml `android:supportsRtl="true"` .

When I use this code to convert app language, it converts the texts **ONLY**. Without converting the **layout direction**, **text direction** and **text alignment**.

1. This code contains `.locale` and `.updateConfiguration` as java
   code. Can you please to help me how to **cleanup whole** code to be
   **suitable** for kotlin code?
2. Can you please to help me **solve RtL
   problem** to make the app more professional and accuracy app?

Here's attachments to prove the problem.
[image: shows what happens when implement the code. Against to when I change language device]

Answer (score 1):

To make the layout change direction follows to the language add:

- [`setLayoutDirection()` from the View class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setLayoutDirection(int)) on the `window.decorView`
- [`setLayoutDirection()` from the Configuration class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#setLayoutDirection(java.util.Locale)) on the `res.configuration`

  ```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
       res.configuration.setLayoutDirection(language)
       window.decorView.layoutDirection = if (rtl) View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL else View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
   }
  ```

In the above snippet make sure to replace `if(rtl)` with RTL condition for instance `if (language == "ar")`

You can call this code in the activity's `onCreate()`, but also test it inside your `setLocale()` method

Comment: Firstly. Thanks so much for your help ☺☺. Secondly your code worked very well but after so small amendment. And I will add this as a answer to publish it.

Answer (score 1):

@Zain **has replied to me** and I thank him so much. But I **developed** the answer to be totally working.

```
@SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    private fun setLocale(lang: String) {
        val language = Locale(lang)
        val res: Resources = resources
        val dm: DisplayMetrics = res.displayMetrics
        val conf: Configuration = res.configuration
        conf.locale = language
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            res.configuration.setLayoutDirection(language)
            (if (lang == "ar") {
                View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
            } else {
                View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
            }).also { window.decorView.layoutDirection = it }
        }
        val refresh = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(refresh)
        finish()
    }
```

so I changed:

1. in `if` expression I used `lang` constructor and variable `language` . Because the variable won't declare in `if` as a logic test, expect after declare it in `val` as `String`. So, the **correct** to use the constructor.
2. I added braces for all `if` expression.
3. I converted assignment to **assignment expression**.
4. I added **suppress annotation** `@SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")`.

And to be honest, I implemented no. 2, 3, and 4 **from Show Context Action** AndroidStudio